# How lombok flag usage with WARNING?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, lombok

I want to log the usage of the lombok feature @EqualsAndHashCode in my Vaadin / Spring Boot project. Therefor I add the file `src/main/java/lombok.config` with `lombok.equalsAndHashCode.flagUsage=WARNING`. [ BTW place this file in `src/main/resources` and assume its copied by maven into target classpath folder didn't work.]
If I set the configuration key to ERROR, the maven compilation failed with appropriate logs, mentioned the usage of the annotation @EqualsAndHashCode in certain files.

But HOW lombok  act if this configuartion is set to `WARNING` ? I didn't see any warnings, neither during compile nor runtime ?